# bin/magento error after update

Tags: magento2.3.1, shell

Hello i have updated from 2.2.8 to 2.3.1 now **`php bin/magento`** is not working:

php bin/magento list

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend\Mvc\Controller\LazyControllerAbstractFactory' not found in .../vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:314
Stack trace:
#0 .../vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/Config.php(137): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->addAbstractFactory('Zend\\Mvc\\Contro...')
#1 .../vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/ServiceListener.php(225): Zend\ServiceManager\Config->configureServiceManager(Object(Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager))
#2 [internal function]: Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ServiceListener->onLoadModulesPost(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
#3 .../vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
#4 .../vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(248): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger in .../vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php on line 314
```

Comment: check this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15441

Comment: great, that worked for me. i googled the error but no result like that. thank you

Comment: this solved the issue: github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15441 thanks to magefms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the upgrade instructions here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html should take care of this issue. In particular for this error make sure to update your autoload section.

Comment: Where is the solution described in https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15441 explained in the DevDocs link you provided? I'm not able to find it.

Comment: I believe the linked page changed and has removed the relevant content. This is why you should always include the relevant content in the answer instead of just linking to it. The answer by @SumanPradhan works for me.

Answer (score 9):

The issue can be fixed by manually editing composer.json autoload section to

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
        "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
    }
}
```

and then run

```
composer dumpautoload
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

It will work.

Comment: This answer is useful

Comment: Hello Please run below command and issues fixed.
composer require laminas/laminas-zendframework-bridge

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `"Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"` in `autoload` -> `psr-4` in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
  "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
  "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
  "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
  "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
},
"psr-0": {
  "": [
    "app/code/",
    "generated/code/"
  ]
},
"files": [
  "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
],
"exclude-from-classmap": [
  "**/dev/**",
  "**/update/**",
  "**/Test/**"
]
},
```

Don't forget to :

```
composer update
```

And other Magento commands like as

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento cache:clean
```